# How to center character | in a before element

Tags: html, css

I have been having some trouble lately with an element that's refusing from being styled.

Here is what i'm trying to achieve :

[image]
Here is what i have right now :

[image]

I have tried to apply various styling elements, like `vertical-align: middle`, some `padding` or some `margin` without much success.

My guess is that it's blocked by it's container and cannot go any "higher" that what the container is.

I'd like to keep this solution (the | in the before element) while having them centered.

Is it possible?

Here's my css / html so far :

CSS :

```
/**********Header**********/
#head-wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.menu_align{
    padding-top: 8px;
    float: right;
}

nav a + a:before{
    content: " | ";
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102); /*needed in order to prevent color triggering from hover property of a*/
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

HTML :

```
    <header>
        <div id="head-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>Images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            <nav class="menu_align">
                <a href="#">INSIGHT</a>
                <a href="#">BUILDINGS</a>
                <a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Use CSS borders for the borders between your menu items, don't generate ASCII art content.

Comment: You could position absolute the '|' and give top and left values.

Comment: @Quentin Haha, true enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use pseudo elements and the pipe character to split your navigation items. Give a border to the anchors and then remove the border for the `first-child`:

```
nav a{
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
nav a:first-child{
    border-left:0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/9ZELC/1/)

---

The above is the most widely-supported option, however there are others, that will only work in newer (IE9+) browsers:

```
nav a:not(:first-child){
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/9ZELC/3/)

Comment: Probably a matter of personal taste, but I don't like solutions that "do something, then undo the same for one case". If you use `nav a:not(:first-child)` for the first selector, then you won't need the second selector at all.

Comment: @MrLister Except for the part where some browsers don't support the not selector.  It would be more efficient to make use of the adjacent selector.

Comment: @MrLister It's a good suggestion, my only mention would be supportability. As `:first-child` is supported in IE since 7, but `:not` isn't until 9

Comment: @cimmanon Sure, but the adjacent selector `a + a` is also relatively new, and older browsers don't all support that either.

Comment: Supporting older browsers isn't really necessary for the type of stuff i'm currently doing, although it's always a +. Would you mind including the nav a:not solution to your answer?

Comment: And yes, thanks btw :), where are my manners! Also, you forgot a `;` after border-left: 0, was it intended?

Comment: It's not completely necessary as it is the last property being set within the class - however it's definitely good practice to have it there anyway! Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZELC/2/)

```
<ul>
       <li><a href="#">INSIGHT</a></li><li>|</li>
       <li><a href="#">BUILDINGS</a></li><li>|</li>
       <li><a href="#">CLIENTS</a></li>
<ul>
```

Good Luck....

Comment: That's even worse than what the OP had.